# Capybara not allowing website session to timeout of inactive account

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I need to test a condition where a user who is logged in would be logged out automatically due to inactivity. I set the configuration so that if the user is inactive for a minute, he would be logged out.

When I test this manually, it seems to work fine

However, if I add a sleep time of 70 secs in my test, the user does not get logged out. Is it because capybara keeps interacting with the website?

How can I solve this issue?

Note: I am using Capybara - cucumber - Ruby

Answer (score 0):

I don't think capybara makes any activity by itself.

Keeping an eye on

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

or (if you're on heroku)

```
heroku logs --tail
```

during the 70 seconds will tell you whether there is indeed activity.